# Java based configuration of Spring DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a task to make my JAR application a Spring MVC application. I installed Tomcat 9.0.5 and proceeded to configure spring. For my sample test application, I decided to go with 100% Java configuration of DispatcherServlet and no web.xml as instructed here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-servlet but I can't make it work.

I created a project using IntelliJ. It downloaded spring jars and created a directory structure like that:

```
tomcattest
|-.idea
|-lib
|-out
|-src
|-web
||-index.jsp
|-tomcattest.iml
```

I run this empty application under my Tomcat and index.jsp has been loaded.

Then I created `MyWebApplicationInitializer`:

```
package pl.mesayah.tomcattest;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

`AppConfig`:

```
package pl.mesayah.tomcattest;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("pl.mesayah.tomcattest")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

And sample `@RestController`:

```
package pl.mesayah.tomcattest;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

But I can't make it work. After deploying to Tomcat I can still see index.jsp page but going to http://localhost:8080/test gives 404 error page and It's Tomcat's 404, not Spring's. So I thought that DispatcherServlet isn't working at all, but I have no idea how to do it. I was following official Spring documentation from the link above.

Please, tell me what I am missing in my code.

Comment: Enable debug logging and post what's logged during startup and during and after that request.

Comment: Can you also add your own logging statements in the `MyWebApplicationInitializer` methods to verify they are being called.  Essentially, want to first determine if Spring is even being initialized or if it's not.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just going with Boot for a new project?

Comment: How can I change logging level in Spring application (not Boot), examples from google cover mostly Spring Boot. The reason I don't use Spring Boot is a specific requirement from a boss.

Comment: I've just spotted that I have no info logging from spring, so it's not bootstrapping at all.